# How do condition mid-string

Tags: string, powershell, conditional-statements

I have a string in my psobject and it will only apply for 10 devices but not the 11th one.  How do I construct a string and not include one variable if it's the 11th one?

This is what works for the first 10 in my foreach:

```
$INFO_Tab = New-Object psobject -Property $([ordered]@{
                DEVICE = "$($currentDevice)"
                Platform = "Name"
                Device_Error_Description = "ErrorCodeList files \Retail\Tools\ServiceEndToEnd\ErrorCodeList "
                OCP_Display = "sdkDesc in $BaseName $($cppFile)" #$BaseName doesn't apply for $currentDevice="Scanner"
                ...
})
$xlsx = $INFO_Tab | Export-Excel -Path $outFilePathExcel -WorksheetName "Source" -Autosize -AutoFilter -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow  -PassThru
```

Can I do something like this for the OCP_Display line? I can't find an example.

```
OCP_Display = "sdkDesc in"+ if($currentDevice="Scanner"):"":$BaseName +$($cppFile)"
```

This is with PowerShell 5.1 and VSCode.

Comment: `OCP_Display = if ($currentDevice -eq "Scanner") { # do this } else { # do that }`

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. The code would be more readable if you just put the name of the thing in an intermediate variable and then include that variable in the output string.

Comment: @dan-gph - if I can avoid 11 lines of code in if statements above the psobject creation, and boil it down to one sub-expression in the psobject string, I'd rather do that.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'm just trying to keep my code cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `if` statement in a subexpression `$()`:

```
"sdkDesc in $(if($currentDevice -ne 'Scanner'){"$BaseName "})$($cppFile)"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need `$()` not just `()` even outside a string.  Aside from that, it helps to know powershell basics.

```
$currentdevice = 'Unscanner'
$basename = 'Basename'
$cppfile = 'Cppfile'
"Prefix" + $(if($currentDevice -eq "Scanner"){""}else{$BaseName}) + $cppFile

PrefixBasenameCppfile


$currentdevice = 'scanner'
"Prefix" + $(if($currentDevice -eq "Scanner"){""}else{$BaseName}) + $cppFile

PrefixCppfile
```